# Is there a word which is exactly the antonym of "delicious" or "succulent"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I searched a lot, but I ended up with a few words like "distasteful" n ol which are provided in the internet as antonyms however they are do not exactly refer to food which taste bad. I am looking for a word which I can use for food that tastes terrible.

Example:

> My mother prepares succulent food, but today its ______ (terrible), seems like someone else has prepared it.

Comment: 1) 'succulent' is not exactly 'delicious' (but may imply it), so which one do you want the antonym of? 2) How is 'distasteful' _not_ what you are looking for? (you haven't told us how to judge a possible antonym)

Comment: *today it's **not***

Comment: If u guys don't know exactly what m i looking for..then its rather better if u shut ur mouth up and let others help with what they have..

Comment: charming, and if users don't know what you're asking then maybe the fault lies with you. The question is confusing. After all, English is not always child's play, sometimes a little effort is required in order to reap the rewards.

Answer (score 5):

A quick word, first - **succulent** is not necessarily synonymous with **delicious**. **Succulent** specifically refers to something being moist or juicy. So we'd be looking for a couple of different antonyms!

As an antonym for **delicious**, based on the idea that delicious food is attractive, let me suggest

> **Revolting**:
>
> causing intense disgust; disgusting.
>
> **Disgusting**:
>
> arousing revulsion or strong indignation.

Both imply being repelled by the food, rather than attracted.

For **succulent**, you should focus on the dryness as the source of the unpleasantness:

> **Charred**
>
> **Overcooked**
>
> **Leathery**

Comment: For meat, *tough* also works.

Answer (score 3):

Might I suggest **unpalatable** and its [11 synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/unpalatable)?

> **Unpalatable**, adj.
>
> 1. not palatable; unpleasant to the taste.
> 2. disagreeable or unacceptable; obnoxious:

Answer (score 1):

Etymologically, "disgust" refers to a bad taste. (Cf. "gustation", the faculty of tasting.)